# How to set partition count while reading CSV extract using SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm reading a CSV extract using `sparkSession` and the framework is trying to create 10K partitions/tasks because of this huge task count, the spark job was failing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

Below is the sample code which is creating 10K tasks while reading the extract:

```
sparkSession
    .read
    .csv(dfwAbsHdfsPath)
```

Is there any way I can reduce or configure the tasks/partitions count? Just to add, we are using Spark version 2.3.1.

Comment: Is it only 1 CSV file?

Comment: No, it is a csv folder

Comment: How many files?

Comment: It is around 50-60K files, mostly all are in KB size

Comment: Okay, can you check if my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default parallelism in the config like this:

```
.config("spark.default.parallelism", NUMBER)
```

This influences the partitioning.

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried setting this config at both ‘sqlContext’ and ‘sparkContext’ level. I could see still the partitioning count remaining the same